# password check using hashmap

Tags: java, passwords, hashmap

I want to check username and password using this action listener method 
but I always get Wrong password!

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    String uN = usernameFiled.getText();
    String pass = passwordField.getPassword().toString();
    //

    if (uN.isEmpty() || pass.isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginPage.this, "Fields should not be empty!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
    }



    HashMap<String, User> users =  UserDAO.getInstance().getUsers();

    User temp = users.get(uN);

    if (temp.getPassword().equals(pass)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginPage.this, "Login successfull", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }

    else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginPage.this, "Wrong username or password", "Error ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    }
});
```

What is the problem of code??

Comment: Firstly, that you appear to be storing passwords in plain text... beyond that, it's hard to say for sure - what diagnostics have you performed?

Comment: What does `User#getPassword` actually return?  Don't forget that it's (correctly) case sensitve.  Don`t use `passwordField.getPassword().toString()` it's a security risk.  Password comparisons should be done using some kind of hashing algorithm instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JPasswordField#getPassword` returns the text contained in this TextComponent in `char[]`. `char[].toString()` does not return the string value, `array.toString` actually returns the name of the variable and hascode.

you should call `new String(passwordField.getPassword())` or `String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword())`

try -

```
String pass = new String(passwordField.getPassword());
```

or

```
String pass = String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword());
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to up-vote this, except it introduces a security hole

Comment: What is that security hole, could you please explain?

Comment: By converting the password from a `char[]` to a `String`, which becomes interned in the JRE (for the time the JRE is running), you make it possible for someone to inspect the memory and find the password in clear text.  This is why the `getPassword` method exists

Answer (score 0):

`passwordField.getPassword()` return `char[]`. So by calling toString() give you the object string of `char[]`.So, The statement you are using, do not give you password.

```
String pass = passwordField.getPassword().toString();
```

Use it in following way.

```
String pass = new String(passwordField.getPassword());
```